# dotnetzip zipping large files - Unity app stops responding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotnetzip

I'm using dotnetzip in my Unity3d Project for zipping/unzipping files. I am using a code similar to below to zip some part zip files. If the files are small everything works as expected. But if these files are large(each one around 100mb) then the Unity app(exe) stops responding. I don't get any errors. But I think it's due to memory issues because it works if the files are small.
Can you please tell me how to fix this issue.

```
  String[] filenames = { "ReadMe.txt", "c:\\data\\ABC_ExportContent.zip.001", "c:\\data\\ABC_ExportContent.zip.002", "c:\\data\\ABC_ExportContent.zip.003"};
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddFiles(filenames);
    zip.Save("Archive.zip");
  }
```

Update - Today I tested this with the Task Manager opened, and the app becomes not responding due to CPU usage goes to 100%. Not actually due to memory as I guessed.
Please let me know how to overcome this issue.

Update 2 - Since I couldn't find a solution for this, decided to move to SharpZipLib and so far it seems to be doing good.

Comment: If you crash, then there is an Exception with a Stack Trace.  Could you please show them to us

Comment: Hi Richard, as I mentioned in my question what happens is Unity stop responding. I have put try catch in the code and running the Unity app in debug mode. But I don't get any errors in the log. When this happens I have to go to task manager and kill the app. Thanks

Comment: You might want to take out the parts of  your question which refers to a crash, given that you're stated in comments that the app doesn't crash, and this is going to confuse people.

Comment: Thanks Poldie. I removed the word crash.

Comment: Have you waited enough for it to end?

Comment: Yes Jcl, I think so. When I test in a Windows 7 machine  after waiting for a long time, I need to kill the process. In a Windows 8 machine I have to restart the machine, Even task manager doesn't respond when this happens. Whole computer seems to freeze.

Comment: Btw. if you need to do a lot of exporting or other repetitive tasks, uTomate (http://www.ancientlightstudios.com/utomate/) may be an option for you. It also contains an action for zipping up stuff (http://www.ancientlightstudios.com/utomate/documentation/actiondocs/build_zip_file.html). And it's designed to keep Unity responsive while it's doing it's work.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

We got this fixed by using SharpZipLib instead of dotnetzip.